# Are environment variables affected after impersonating and loading a user profile in a service?

Tags: c++, winapi, service, environment-variables

I have a Windows service running under a LocalSystem account and I am trying to access some user-specific environment variables. When I call ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%"), I get "C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming".

I figured impersonation and loading the user profile should solve this, so I called:

- LogonUser()
- LoadUserProfile()
- CreateEnvironmentBlock()
- ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()

And still, ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") returns the the system folder instead of something like "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming".

So then I searched around some more and came across SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA), which worked like a charm post-impersonation.

My question is not what I should do (ie. SHGetFolderPath), but more about how environment variables work in services. I'm thinking my issue is either:

1. My LoadUserProfile() code is still missing something, even though everything returns success. My ignorant side wants to convince me that in theory, loading a user profile should make ExpandEnvironmentStrings() return the loaded user's values.
2. Based on some readings, it seems environment variables in services are read only once (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887693) at system startup, so my service is ONLY aware of system environment variables.

I'm leaning towards 2. but I just need someone to confirm this, so I don't assume something that's potentially wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The docs for Environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicate that #2 is correct. Quoting, emphasis added:

> Every **process** has an environment block that contains a set of
>   environment variables and their values.

MSDN points to [`ExpandEnvironmentStringForUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to approach your original problem.

Comment: Which is why I thought [CreateEnvironmentBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270(v=vs.85).aspx) would get the user's environment variables. The MSDN documentation for it can't be more straight-forward than, "Retrieves the environment variables for the specified user."

Edit: Then again, I suppose this would work only if I called CreateProcessAsUser(), AND THEN be able to access my user's environment variables in that new process.

Comment: @ykay: `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` merely allocates a memory block containing the environment values, but then you have to actually apply that memory block to something. You cannot apply it to the calling process, but you can apply it to a new process.

Comment: Of course, you can read the variable block returned from `CreateEnvironmentBlock`, but you have to do it by hand - there are no API functions for doing so that I'm aware of.